# What do the various Android view in Eclipse do?

Tags: android, eclipse, treeview, view

Does anyone know what the various android views in eclipse do.
Specifically the "tree overview", "tree view", "view properties" and "layout view"
You can access them via Window..Show View... Other... Android

I can't find out any documentation on them or work out what they do. I've clicked on classes and layouts but they never seem to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ADT 9.0.0 all those views disappeared in Eclipse and apparently moved back to the `hierarchyviewer`.

However with ADT 8.0.0 and ADT 8.0.1 you have those view options.

**Tree View**

The `Tree View` depicts your layout as a tree hierarchy. It just shows your layouts view hierarchy. If you click on one of the view elements you get its `View Properties`.

**View Properties**

By clicking on one of the view elements in the `Tree View` you can view the elements view properties in this view. Things like layout options.

**Tree Overview**

The `Tree Overview` just allows you to navigate through your tree hierarchy more easily if the hierarchy happens to be quite big.

**Layout View**

Using the `Layout View` you can inspect your layout element by element. It just shows all your layout elements relative to each other. You can view them like a wireframe.

To use all those views you first have to connect a device to the computer or start an emulator and start an activity whose layout you want to inspect. Open the `Windows` view in Eclipse, select the activity you want to fetch the layout from and hit the `Load the view hierarchy into the tree view`. From now on you can use all the different views as described above.

Keep in mind that all of those views are no longer in Eclipse but again in the standalone `hierarchyviewer` in your `sdk/tools` directory.

Comment: Thanks for that Octavian. I did try clicking on view elements before the ADT update a few days ago but it didn't show anything back then. The view options are also still available in my Eclipse even with ADT 9.0.0. Not really a big deal. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: Very interesting. For me those views are gone.